# Как послать эмейл посредством PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

Тестовая php-страничка. Выдает ошибку:
"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::SMTPAuth() in...."

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

// Pear Mail Library

require_once "../mailer/src/PHPMailer.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail -> isSMTP();
$mail -> SMTPAuth() = true;
$mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail -> Port = '465';
$mail -> isHTML();
$mail -> Username = 'email1@gmail.com';
$mail -> Password = 'password';
$mail -> setFrom('no-reply@xaminer.com');
$mail -> Subject = 'Thank you for registration!';
$mail -> Body = 'To confirm this email, enter this link:';
$mail -> addAddress(email2@gmail.com');

$mail -> Send();
```

(Эмейлы и пароли изменены)

Подскажите. где исправить, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас ошибка вот здесь:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth() = true;
```

Надо вот так:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
```

Будьте внимательнее в следующий раз.